# Output wrong Project Euler 7

Tags: c++

So I'm trying out Problem 7 of Project Euler.

By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
What is the 10 001st prime number?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int a){
    if (a==2||a==3){
        return true;
    }
    if (a%2==0){
        return false;
    }

    bool prime=true;
    for (int b=2;b<sqrt(a);b++){
        if (a%b==0)
            prime=false;

    }
    if (prime==true)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

int main(){
    int infinite=0;
    long long int primecounter=0;
    for (int c=2;infinite==0;c++){
        if (isPrime(c)==true){
            primecounter++;
            //cout<<c<<endl;
            if (primecounter==10001)
                {cout<<c;

            break;}
        }
    }
    return 0;}
```

This is what I've come up with so far. It works for the few numbers that I tested, like the 6th prime number etc. However, when I run it for the 10001st prime, it gives me 104021, and the answer is wrong. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Efficiency note: you can start `b` from `3` and use `b += 2`. Even better, if you keep the previous primes in memory, you need only to get the `%` over those prime numbers and not all numbers.

Comment: You also don't need the middle condition in `for(int c=2;infinite==0;c++)` - if you mean never terminate you can just leave it empty `for(int c=2;;c++)`.

Comment: Side notes: You can write `return prime;`! Also, instead of `infinite == 0`, you can write `true` (or even nothing) and remove infinite altogether. Furthermore, `if (isPrime(c))` is perfectly valid.

Comment: And also check only the numbers above 3 with a format of 6n±1.

Comment: @Shahbaz I just started learning C++. Could you shed some light on how I could keep the previous primes in memory :D

Comment: Get an array of size `10001` (`primes`), each time write `c` to `primecounter` (so 2 would get in location 0). Pass `primes` to `isPrime`. Change `for (int b=2;b<sqrt(a);b++)` to `for (int i = 1; primes[i]*primes[i] <= a; ++i)` and check `a%primes[i] == 0`. I started `i` from 1, because `primes[0]` is 2, and you have already checked `a%2`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where you get it wrong is `b < sqrt(a)`. Think of a=25, what happens in this case?

*rest of answer already pointed by comments*.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not required for this specific problem, you should take a look at [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm. You will need it sooner or later to solve prime related problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without getting help from 'cmath' too.Logic is like...
To check whether a number is prime, set a counter variable to 0; write a loop to divide the number by every number less than it till 1. If a number completely divides it, the counter will increase by one; the counetr will be exactly 2 for a prime number.
To calculate sucha big number u should choose a proper datatype too.I have used 'long long int' as a datatype.
My code  for the project euler problem no 7 is as follows.Hope it helps you.Best wishes.Editions and improvements in this program are most welcome.Only bug is the time that it consumes,it takes more than an hour to reach the 10001th prime number.

```
        #include<iostream.h>
        #include<conio.h>
          class prime
             {
              long long int a;
              long long int j,i;
               public:
             void display();
              };

        void prime::display()
             {
                  j=0;
                 long long int count=0;
                 long long int count1=0;
               while(count1!=10001)
                 {
                     j=j+1;
                     i=j;
                     while(i!=0)
                   {
                       if(j%i==0)
                          {
                            count++;
                           }
                       i--;
                    }
                     if(count==2)
                        {
                           count1++;
                           cout<<count1<<"\t";  //The serial number of the prime number.

                           cout<<j<<"\t";// This will diaply all prime numbers till 10001.

                         }
                   if(count1==10001)
                        {
                          cout<<"\nThe 10001th prime number is:"<<j;
                         }
                      count=0;
                  }
               }

                     void main()
                         {
                              prime k;
                              clrscr();                                 
                              k.display();
                              getch();
                          }
```